# Como recuperar o valor separadamente de input numbers com mesma classe

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html5

Bom, estou tendo um pequeno probleminha em fazer com que o valor inserido no input number de alguns cards que eu criei... 
Basicamente, ele está repetindo o valor em todos os inputs de todos os cards
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Todos os inputs estão com a mesma classe, e sempre que clico no botão adicionar ou digito um valor, ele altera em todos eles.

Aqui é o código das divs com os card

```
  <div class="tab-content produtos">
                        <div class="tab-pane fade show active" role="tabpanel" id="tab-2">
                            <div class="card-group d-inline-flex align-items-center  flex-wrap">
                                <div class="card flex-wrap item-cardapio produto">
                                    <div class="card-body d-flex flex-column align-items-center">
                                        <img class="img-fluid imagem-produto" src="assets/img/aea6de9cbaee9d2704dcf81f4a194991-754x394.jpg">
                                        <h4 class="card-title titulo-produto">Title</h4>
                                        <h5 class="preco-produto">R$0,00</h5>
                                        <p class="card-text descricao-produto">Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus.</p>
                                        <div class="d-flex flex-column quantidade-produto"><span class="m-auto">Quantidade</span>
                                            <div class="m-auto quantidade">
                                                <button class="btn btn-danger qtd-botoes qtd-remove" type="button">-</button>
                                                <input type="number" value="0" min="0" class="qtd-produto">
                                                <button class="btn btn-danger qtd-botoes qtd-add" type="button">+</button></div>
                                        </div>
                                        <button class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-block btn-adicionar-carrinho" type="button">Adicionar ao Carrinho</button></div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="card flex-wrap item-cardapio">
                                    <div class="card-body d-flex flex-column align-items-center"><img class="img-fluid imagens-cardapio" src="assets/img/aea6de9cbaee9d2704dcf81f4a194991-754x394.jpg">
                                        <h4 class="card-title">Title</h4>
                                        <h5>R$0,00</h5>
                                        <p class="card-text">Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus.</p>
                                        <div class="d-flex flex-column"><span class="m-auto">Quantidade</span>
                                            <div class="m-auto quantidade"><button class="btn btn-danger qtd-botoes qtd-remove" type="button">-</button><input type="number" value="0" min="0" class="qtd-produto"><button class="btn btn-danger qtd-botoes qtd-add" type="button">+</button></div>
                                        </div><button class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-block btn-adicionar-carrinho" type="button">Adicionar ao Carrinho</button></div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="card flex-wrap item-cardapio">
                                    <div class="card-body d-flex flex-column align-items-center"><img class="img-fluid imagens-cardapio" src="assets/img/aea6de9cbaee9d2704dcf81f4a194991-754x394.jpg">
                                        <h4 class="card-title">Title</h4>
                                        <h5>R$0,00</h5>
                                        <p class="card-text">Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus.</p>
                                        <div class="d-flex flex-column"><span class="m-auto">Quantidade</span>
                                            <div class="m-auto quantidade"><button class="btn btn-danger qtd-botoes qtd-remove" type="button">-</button><input type="number" value="0" min="0" class="qtd-produto"><button class="btn btn-danger qtd-botoes qtd-add" type="button">+</button></div>
                                        </div><button class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-block btn-adicionar-carrinho" type="button">Adicionar ao Carrinho</button></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

E aqui é o código JavaScript que eu criei pra incrementar/decrementar o valor do input number toda vez que clicar nos botões +/-

```
var qtdAdd = $(".qtd-add");
var qtdRemove = $(".qtd-remove");
var produto = $(".qtd-produto");

qtdAdd.click(adicionaQtd);
qtdRemove.click(removeQtd);
function adicionaQtd(){
  var qtd = parseInt(produto.val());
  qtdAdiciona = qtd + 1;
  $(".qtd-produto").val(qtdAdiciona);

}
function removeQtd(){
  var qtd = parseInt(produto.val());
  if(qtd == 0){
      return false;
  }else{
      qtdRemove = qtd - 1;
      $(".qtd-produto").val(qtdRemove);
  }   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No *JavaScript* você precisa guardar o objeto/elemento clicado usando `$(this)` e enviá-lo para a função.

Em seguida use `el.closest()` para subir 1 nível do elemento clicado e chegar na `div.quantidade`, a seguir use `find()` para encontrar o *input* dentro dessa *div*.

Segue demo no JSFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/amo39hpL/25/

Comment: Muito obrigado cara :D 
Ainda to iniciando com desenvolvimento web, e acabei aprendendo algo que não conhecia, que é o método closest(), e preciso praticar mais, ainda fico confuso com o uso do this